# When recasting in Swift, when do you use "<object> as <type>" and when to use <type>(<object>)

Tags: swift, casting

For example this code works:

```
var i = 5
var  str: String
str = String(i)
```

but this does not:

```
str = i as String
```

On the other hand this code works.

```
let controller : MyViewController
controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as! MyViewController
```

but this does not:

```
controller = MyViewController(storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController"))
```

Comment: Unrelated, I'd suggest renaming your `UIViewController` subclass to start with an uppercase letter, e.g. `MyViewController`. By convention, variable names, enumerations, etc., start with lowercase letters, but data types, such as class names, should always start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: You have to know the difference between casting and creating new instance. You simply cannot cast to unrelated type.

Answer (score 3):

`String(i)` is used to create a `String` object from another value (`Int` in this case`). This is the proper way to convert from one type to another. This is not a cast.

`i as String` is a cast, not a conversion. Casting does not alter the actual object's type. Since `i` is an `Int`, you can't simply cast it to a `String`. Casting is typically done when you get a reference to an object using a base class or maybe `Any` and you wish to have a variable that specifies the actual data type of the object.

In your second example you declared a variable with a type of `myViewController`. Presumably this is a subclass of `UIViewController`. The use of `as! myViewController` works because you setup your storyboard indicating that the view controller with the identifier of `"myViewController"` is really of type `myViewController`. The call to `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` has a return type of `UIViewController`. So the cast (`as! myViewController`) allows you to indicate that the `UIViewController` really is a `myViewController`. It fails without the cast because you can't assign a value of type `UIViewController` to a variable of type `myViewController` (but you could do the reverse).

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: There are also "bridging casts" which do alter the type: `let i = 5; let n = i as NSNumber`

Answer (score 1):

The title of the question asks:

> when do you use “<object> `as` <type>” and when to use <type>`(`<object>`)`

These two patterns are designed to solve very different data type issues:

- We use the former syntax when we have an `object` that is of some type, but where you happen to know that it is (or want to test whether it is) really an instance of some subclass of that type and you need/want to access some property/method unique to that subclass.

  In your `instantiateViewController` example, that method is defined to return `UIViewController`. The `instantiateViewController` method has no way of knowing whether your storyboard scene may have specified some `UIViewController` subclass as the "base class" for that scene, so it returns a `UIViewController` reference. But you happen to know that the scene in question actually returns some custom subclass of `UIViewController`, so you can [downcast](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID341) as your `MyViewController` subclass. You'd generally do that if you need to interact with some property/method unique to your `UIViewController` subclass.

  Note, nowadays, you don't use `as` for downcasting. You'd either use `as!` to do a forced downcast if you know with 100% certainty that the downcast will succeed. Or you'd use `as?` as a safe way to test if the cast succeeded (e.g. with an `if let` or `guard let` construct).
- We use the latter syntax when you want to create an entirely new instance of some other type.

  Consider:

  ```
  let string = String(i)
  ```

  This actually is creating a new `String` instance, using `i` during its initialization.

  This wouldn't make sense in the `instantiateViewController` example, because we don't want to create a new `MyViewController` instance from what that method returned. Rather we merely want to tell the compiler "yes, I know that method will return `UIViewController` (or subclass) instance, but I happen to know it's really `MyViewController` instance." So, in that case, we use the `as!` (or `as?`) downcast.

As Martin R points out, there are other types of casts (bridging casts, casts of `Any` and `AnyObject` types, etc.). But that's not relevant for your particular example.

For a general discussion of casting, see [Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338) section of *The Swift Programming Language.* See [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35) for discussion of bridging types, `id` casts, etc.